# How to fix Fatal error Deprecated Functionality after upgrade magento version 2.4.5

Tags: magento2.4.2, magento-upgrade, magento2.4.5, version-upgrade

**How to fix below error.**

```
PHP Fatal error:  During inheritance of IteratorAggregate: Uncaught Exception: Deprecated Functionality: 
Return type of Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\HelperSet::getIterator() should either be compatible with IteratorAggregate::getIterator(): 
Traversable, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /
```

Answer (score 2):

[image]

#[\ReturnTypeWillChange] add this above the function like screenshot.

It will work

Comment: Thanks. It works for Magento v2.4.6.